# display: table-cell; and transform: rotate(180deg); and text-rotate : 180; not works IN mPDF

Tags: mpdf

I'm trying to make this code below work in mPDF, but it gives error.

However, browsing in the browser gives no error.

I hope to find a result like in the image below.

Note that display: table-cell; and transform: rotate(180deg); and text-rotate : 180; works in the browser.

[image: Anotação 2019-03-21 092449]

Follow my code:

```
<?php 

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $css  = '
        <style>
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            div.tabela {
                display: table;
                width: 870px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                border: 1px #000 solid;
            }

            div.tabela div.titulos {
                background-color: #CCC;
            }

            div.tabela div.registros {
                height: 30px;
                border-top: none;
            }

            div.tabela div.titulos, 
            div.tabela div.registros {  
                display: table-row;
                width: 100%;
            }

            div.tabela div.titulos div, 
            div.tabela div.registros div {
                display: table-cell;
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle;
                border-left: 1px #000 solid;
            }

            div.tabela div.titulos div:nth-child(1), 
            div.tabela div.registros div:nth-child(1) {
                border-left: none;
            }

            span {}

            span.normal {}

            span.rotate {
                height: 200px;
                writing-mode: vertical-rl;
                transform: rotate(180deg);
                                text-rotate : 180;
                transform-origin: center;
            }

        </style>
    ';

    $body = '       

        <div class="tabela">

            <div class="titulos">

                <div style="width: 100px;"><span class=normal>Nome do Gcéu</label></div>
                <div style="width: 100px;"><span class=rotate>Supervisor</label></div>
                <div style="width: 100px;"><span class=normal>Líder</label></div>
                <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Houve Supervisão?</label></div>
                <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Houve dia de Jejum?</label></div>
                <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Houve dia de Evangelismo?</label></div>
                <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Membros Compromissados</label></div>
                <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Visitantes</label></div>
                <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Crianças de 0 a 12 anos</label></div>
                <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Total de presentes</label></div>
                <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Ofertas</label></div>
                <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Discipulados</label></div>
                <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Número de decisões</label></div>

            </div>

        </div>  

        <div class="tabela">

            <div class="registros">

                <div style="width: 100px;">Gceú</div>
                <div style="width: 100px;">Carlos</div>
                <div style="width: 100px;">Cleo</div>
                <div style="width: 050px;">Sim</div>
                <div style="width: 050px;">Sim</div>
                <div style="width: 050px;">Não</div>
                <div style="width: 050px;">12</div>
                <div style="width: 050px;">3</div>
                <div style="width: 050px;">3</div>
                <div style="width: 050px;">18</div>
                <div style="width: 050px;">12.3</div>
                <div style="width: 050px;">2</div>
                <div style="width: 050px;">1</div>

            </div>  

        </div>

    ';

    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode( 'fullpage' );
    $mpdf->WriteHTML( $css, 1 );
    $mpdf->WriteHTML( $body );
    $mpdf->Output();

?>
```

Why on the PDF it out with above?

Note that display: table-cell; and transform: rotate(180deg); and text-rotate :

180; not works i PDF.

[image: 22]

New:

```
<?php 

    $css  = '
        <style>

            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            div.titulos {
                height: 200px;
                background-color: #CCC;
            }

            div.registros {
                height: 30px;
                border-top: none;
            }

            div.titulos, 
            div.registros { 
                width: 870px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                border: thin solid #000;
            }

            div.titulos div, 
            div.registros div {
                float: left;
                text-align: center;
                vertical-align: middle;
                border-left: thin solid #000;
            }

            div.titulos div:nth-child(1), 
            div.registros div:nth-child(1) {
                border-left: none;
            }

            span {}

            span.normal {}

            span.rotate {
                height: 200px;
                rotate : -90;
                text-rotate : -90;
                writing-mode: vertical-rl;
                transform: rotate(180deg);
                transform-origin: center;
            }

        </style>
    ';

    $body = '   
            <div class="titulos">

                <div style="width: 100px;"><span class=normal>Nome do Gcéu</span></div>
                <div style="width: 100px;"><span class=rotate>Supervisor</span></div>
                <div style="width: 100px;"><span class=normal>Líder</span></div>
                <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Houve Supervisão?</span></div>
                <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Houve dia de Jejum?</span></div>
                <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Houve dia de Evangelismo?</span></div>
                <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Membros Compromissados</span></div>
                <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Visitantes</span></div>
                <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Crianças de 0 a 12 anos</span></div>
                <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Total de presentes</span></div>
                <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Ofertas</span></div>
                <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Discipulados</span></div>
                <div style="width: 050px;"><span class=rotate>Número de decisões</span></div>

            </div>

            <div class="registros">

                <div style="width: 100px;">Gceú</div>
                <div style="width: 100px;">Carlos</div>
                <div style="width: 100px;">Cleo</div>
                <div style="width: 050px;">Sim</div>
                <div style="width: 050px;">Sim</div>
                <div style="width: 050px;">Não</div>
                <div style="width: 050px;">12</div>
                <div style="width: 050px;">3</div>
                <div style="width: 050px;">3</div>
                <div style="width: 050px;">18</div>
                <div style="width: 050px;">12.3</div>
                <div style="width: 050px;">2</div>
                <div style="width: 050px;">1</div>

            </div>  
    ';

    //echo $css.$body;

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode( 'fullpage' );
    $mpdf->WriteHTML( $css, 1 );
    $mpdf->WriteHTML( $body );
    $mpdf->Output();
```

Now, only the span not rotate.

How to fix it?

Se how it is now:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Property `display: table` is not supported in mPDF. Use an actual HTML `table`.

Also, per documentation, `text-rotate` has only values `1-90` or `-90` supported as per [supported CSS documentation](https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html):

> Rotates the text in a table cell. Accepted values are 1-90 for degrees anticlockwise, or -90 (only) for clockwise rotation. (custom attribute)

Comment: it means that just it possivel work with mPDF working whit HTML table? And divs? It's not possible?

Comment: Divs? Probably not. HTML table will be easy and straightforward solution.

Comment: yes. But, they are not be portable. Example? Table in Mobile?

Comment: mPDF's rendering capabilities are limited. And paper/PDF is a different medium than a responsive web. Deal with it.

Comment: I did other try with float an put it in the end of question and now it's bether. But the spans yet not rotate. Can you helpe me?